# Python, maps between 2 lists

Tags: python, list

we are given two lists A and B of strings with len(A) == len(B). This induces the map between the two lists defined by: A[n]->B[n]. We want to distinguish the following three types of maps:

type 1 is '1-to-m': when there are at least 2 indices m and n such that A[m]==A[n] and B[m]!= B[n]

type 2 is 'm-to-1': when there are at least 2 indices m and n such that A[m]!=A[n] and B[m] ==B[n]

type 3 is 'm-to-m': when it is both 1-to-m and m-to-1

1 to 1: when it is neither 1-to-m nor m-to-1

---

Example: if A = [a b a]  and B = [M N M] then the map is 1 to 1

if A = [a b a] and B = [M N P] then the map is 1-to-m

if A = [a b c] and B = [M M P] then the map is m-to-1

if A = [a a b] and B = [M N N] then the map is m-to-m

is there any clean way to find the type of the map between two lists A , B of the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as heck: Construct the map! We determine what keys map to each value and what values map to each key, and see if any keys or values have multiple matches. [`collections.defaultdict(set)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is used as a convenient way to avoid having to check whether dict keys already have associated sets.

```
import collections

def maptype(keys, values):
    forward = collections.defaultdict(set)
    backward = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        forward[key].add(value)
        backward[value].add(key)

    one_to_m = any(len(l) > 1 for l in forward.values())
    m_to_one = any(len(l) > 1 for l in backward.values())
    return one_to_m, m_to_one
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def m_n(A,B):
    # use set to remove duplicate results
    x = defaultdict(lambda: set)
    y = defaultdict(lambda: set)

    [x[a].add(b) for a, b in zip(A,B)]
    [y[b].add(a) for a, b in zip(A,B)]

    m = [a for a in x if len(x[a]) > 1]
    n = [a for a in y if len(y[a]) > 1]

    if not m and not n:
        return '1-1'

    elif not m and n:
        return 'm-1'

    elif m and not n:
        return '1-m'

    else:
        return 'm-m'


assert m_n(['a', 'b', 'a'],['M', 'N', 'M']) == '1-1'
assert m_n(['a', 'b', 'a'], ['M', "N", "P"]) == '1-m'
assert m_n(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['M', "M", "P"]) == 'm-1'
assert m_n(['a', 'a', 'b'], ['M', "N", "N"]) == 'm-m'
```

Comment: `lambda: set()` can be written more simply as just `set`. Also, using list comprehensions for side effects is bad practice; it's better to use a normal `for` loop and not build a list.